# Playa: search function not working

Tags: playa

Client is telling me neither the Playa search or filter function is working for them on any main browser on Win 7. It must be a problem with his PC as I've not been able to reproduce the problem myself. Could it be something to do with Javascript?
EE v2.7.3
Playa v4.4.5

Comment: Did he have any JS errors? If everything load completely?

Comment: Everything is loading. There seem to be no other problems. I'm not in the position to check for JS errors unfortunately.